# how to calculate discount based on category of products on shopping cart page in opencart?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I want to group and display products on shopping cart page by category wise. I mean to say that, if we have four products, then it should be shown like below:

> ## Category 1
>
> - product i
> - product ii
>
> ## Category 2
>
> - product i
> - product ii

I also would like to store the total amount of each category value, in an array. I'm trying to implement category wise discount.
Thanks.

**EDITED:-**
This is my shopping cart page, where I'm trying to display discount based on the category of products
[image]

Suppose, if there are two products in the cart and they belong to two different category. Now I want to calculate discount based on the number of quantity of each category.
I have created a module in admin section where I'm setting all the required values, and storing it to the table in database.

[image]

Now, based on the values set in the admin I'm trying to implement discount on shopping cart page. But I'm not getting any idea, how could i do that ?

> That's why I have no code to place here.

please give some idea, so that i can try creating something.
thanks!!

Following is my requirement --

> 1. Sale and Delivery Terms:
>
>    - for orders exceeding 600 Francs, delivery is free of charge;
>    - for orders less than the above, a delivery charge of 20 Francs, will apply;
> 2. Discounts and Quantities
>
>    - Red Wines, White Wines:
>
>      - from 36 bottles, each of 750ml, 6% discount;
>      - from 60 bottles, each of 750ml, 10% discount;
>      - from 84 bottles, each of 750ml, 13% discount.
>    - Fortified Wines (sweet):
>
>      - from 12 bottles, each of 750ml, 5% discount.
>    - Discount on Pick up:
>
>      - from 24 bottles, each of 750ml, 3% discount.
>    - Cash Payment:
>
>      - from 24 bottles, each of 750ml, 3% discount.
>    - Cash Payment on Delivery:
>
>      - 3% discount.

Comment: your php and mysql code???

Comment: @Joke_Sense10--- that is general page of opencart, on which i'm trying to do above. but i'm not not getting any idea on how to do it ?
that's why i have not posted any code here !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved as following.
we can sort all the products based on there category and can then apply any discount easily..

First you should sort all paroducts ---

```
////////////// Grouping Same category products into one array //////////////

$category_id = $this->model_discount_cdiscount->getcategory($product['product_id']);

$array_key = $category_id[0]['category_id']; 

if (array_key_exists($array_key, $this->data['discount']))
{

    $this->data['discount'][$array_key]['total'] = $this->data['discount'][$array_key]['total']+(preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/","",$total));
    $this->data['discount'][$array_key]['quantity'] = $this->data['discount'][$array_key]['quantity']+$product['quantity'];
}
else
{
    $this->data['discount'][$array_key] = array(
            'category_name' => $category_id[0]['name'],
            'category_id' => $array_key,
            'total' => (preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/","",$total)),
            'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
            'length' => $product['length']
        );
}
```

and then can apply ---

```
////////////////////// Get Discount values from Discount table //////////////////////

foreach($this->data['discount'] as $key2 => $value2)
{
    $this->data['product_match'][] = $this->model_discount_cdiscount->matchDiscount($key2);
}


//////////////////////  Calculate Discount //////////////////////
$total_d =0;
foreach($this->data['discount'] as $discounts)
{
    foreach($this->data['product_match'] as $match)
    {
        if(count($match)!=0)
        {
            if ($discounts['category_id']==$match['category'] AND $discounts['quantity']>=$match['quantity'] AND $discounts['length']==$match['class_value'])
            {

                $dt = ($match['discount']/100)*$discounts['total'];
                $total_d += $dt;
            }
        }
    }

}
```